# project euler question7 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

my prime function is working fine for numbers greater than 3,i have accounted for that in loop folowing afterward,question is to find 10001st prime
but i am getting wrong answer that is a prime number but not the 10001st,should be 104743

```
def pr(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**(0.5))+1):
        if n%i==0:

        return False
        break   
    else:
        return True
num = 3
count = 2       
while count < 10001:
    num += 1
    x = pr(num)
    if x == True:
        count += 1

print num
```

Comment: Testing primality by dividing by even numbers is not a great idea. Also, note that the `return False` is never executed, because of the `break` and that the `return True` is placed wrong with respect to the logic.

Comment: now what do you u say

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you should figure out your project Euler solutions your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try;

```
def pr(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3,int(n**(0.5))+1,2):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pgen(): # Sieve of Eratosthenes generator
    yield 2
    np_f, q = {}, 3
    while True:
        f = np_f.pop(q, None)
        if f:
            np = q + f
            while np in np_f:
                np += f
            np_f[np] = f
        else:
            yield q
            np_f[q*q] = q+q
        q += 2

>>> p = pgen()
>>> [next(p) for i in xrange(10001)][-1]
104743
```